# Triage audits imply genuine users are spamming (not good)

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, review-audits, triage

[This triage review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6861664), was rendered originally like this:

> [image]

That user is [***an actual person***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1660971/toanant). Displaying their username could easily lead them to being unjustly blamed for spamming, which [wouldn't be nice](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/).

This appears to be a partial regression of the MSE feature request, [Stop using real accounts in suggested edit audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170683/stop-using-real-accounts-in-suggested-edit-audits). If it's not, please consider this a feature request.

Comment: I believe this is "by design", a random low-rep user is displayed first, then once you pass/fail the audit it is replaced by the Community user.

Comment: Maybe @Qantas, in which case this is a feature request.

Comment: That's a really good example you posted here. I think there's some laws for stock photos where you can't use the image of a person in an advertisement for things that might be considered obscene, really embarrassing, etc. However, in this case, I don't think it's that big a deal, since what , like only 1-5 people ever see each audit *(unless you post a screenshot of it on meta)*. I agree with your feature request +1

Comment: We could [use it all](http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/12186251/) :)

Comment: `a random low-rep user is displayed first` - surely randomly generating a user would be simple and better though? For some questions it probably doesn't matter, but putting a real users face alongside this sort of spam in particular isn't very nice.

Comment: @Octopoid Generating realistic users is a difficult problem.  Picking a random low-rep user is easy.

Comment: Is it though? "user" + number, random first name + random letter, with random optional underscore or any number of other random name generating methods. Random rep under 100, few random bronze badges, maybe a silver. Random avatar from any number of sources. You can always fake some sort of error if you try and visit the actual profile page, much like if you try and edit one of the test questions. Maybe I'm missing something - just seems easy enough to me...

Comment: I don't visit meta too often, so there might be something I am not aware of. Why not hide the user information entirely during the reviews? You are supposed to review the content, not the user, right?

Comment: @Happy No, we can't be THAT fair, can we?

Comment: I agreed with @Happy at first, but I'm rethinking it now... Part of due diligence for reviewing may be to look at a user's profile and check their other work. Maybe a "generated" user is better.

Comment: @Michael If that is a generated user though doesn't that make the whole process of checking the user *(in relation to the audit)* pointless? I'm with Happy on this one.

Comment: @Lankymart If there isn't a way to get to the actual author for a non-audit review of spam, we can't check for other places where the author may have spammed. If the profile box is hidden only for audits and shown for non-audits, any doofus is going to notice the pattern. As it stands now, the "random user" already [doesn't hold up under scrutiny](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169249/230855). Maybe hiding the profile box until after the review makes everyone happy?

Comment: **Note:** It sounds like refreshing the page may [cause the user to change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169249/how-did-a-user-who-was-not-online-for-x-hours-propose-a-suggested-edit-in-the-la#comment499640_169249) and so is an exploit that can easily identify audits. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: @Michael Point taken.

Comment: @Michael Attributing the content being reviewed to a random user doesn't help you in any way even in that case. This current method is totally messed up for the following reason: We don't want to show the actual author of the content because it will interfere with the review (I still don't get why). So what's our solution? We attribute it to some other user, of course! How does it help? No idea. Does it cause any harm? Yes, it makes an innocent user look bad. What was his crime? He did not have enough reputation. Am I the only one bemused by the stupidity of reasoning?

Comment: @Michael: wouldn't refreshing the page to check for an audit imply that the user was, at least, paying attention?

Comment: @Happy: perhaps the content is generated?

Comment: This is slander.  Ask the lawyers.  Changing the TOS to say "no its not", or "you consent to it" would not change the fact that it is also simply wrong.  Can't say I'm surprised, when so little was done about the close vote notices attributing the majority reason to people who did not vote for it.

Comment: Suggestion: Many real people here have either no avatar or various non-headshot avatars.  Pick a few dozen open source images that are not pictures of people, make those the avatars for the fake users.  Put the fake users in the user db if it needs to look real,  but don't attribute negative content to real people who didn't write it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The people have spoken, a real user will not be used for triage audits.  The real user who created the spammy post will be used instead.  In a lot of cases this user will have already been deleted which is a giveaway, but this seems better than the alternative.

Comment: Thank you sir! (and thank you for not being another commenter!)

Answer (score 8):

If the perceived problem is that we need to make the audit look realistic, a simple enough solution would be to generate a bunch of null accounts with no activity -- default avatar, user names like `user99348349`.  For the duration of the audit, genuinely make them the author of the post to be audited, but no other posts (perhaps only within the auditor's session, if that's possible).

How many random accounts?  Depends.  If the system can generate and remove an account within one audit session, one per active audit session is enough.  If they need to be permanent, I would start with a hundred and see how it works out.  One is probably too little (regular reviewers would learn to recognize the decoy account), a thousand might be too much (pollution?).

Comment: @user99348349 No offense if you really should exist one day.

Comment: Or just a single "The Triage Queue Example User" user, so that it's clear auditors should be judging the question, not the user.

Comment: @Gus has an excellent point. Why do we feel we need to completely fool reviewers? We can test that they're paying attention just fine with a blatant test. If they're not paying attention, they won't notice the test. If they weren't paying attention but now are because of the test, they'll be looking out for it in future.