# Meta Stack Overflow vs Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, scope, meta, mso-mse-split

Before asking this question, I already read the entire Q&A here: [What kind of questions should we ask on Meta Stack Overflow and on Meta Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250020/what-kind-of-questions-should-we-ask-on-meta-stack-overflow-and-on-meta-stack-ex)

But, I am really still confused. When navigating through the *Meta SO* questions, most of them seems to me *Meta Stack Exchange* questions. I will give you here some real examples of famous questions on Meta SO that for me should be in Meta Stack Exchange (chosen randomly from *votes* and *frequent* sections of Meta SO's questions):

- [When did I get close-vote superpowers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers)
- [50 reputation points to make comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133/50-reputation-points-to-make-comments)
- [Why did I gain/lose reputation? Can I audit my reputation history?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history)
- [Notify me when my flag has been handled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284688/notify-me-when-my-flag-has-been-handled)
- [Add ability to cancel flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252155/add-ability-to-cancel-flags)
- [Should I flag old questions that ought to be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250060/should-i-flag-old-questions-that-ought-to-be-closed)

I can't really understand why these *famous* and *well voted* questions (there are more but I gave just few examples) exist here.

This confusion comes to me, after I asked a question on Meta Stack Exchange that hasn't been answered yet, and I saw questions posted here. Where should I ask [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/can-the-reviews-history-also-include-the-consensus-of-our-reviews)?

Comment: When I read the title the only thing I hoped to see in the question after I clicked the link was "Go".

Comment: @QueueHammer i don't understand what do you mean ?

Comment: your question is "Thing A compared withThing B", but the v.s. can be interpreted as "Group A conflicting Group B". Given the passion in both communities, MSE and MSO, I imagined both sides seeing the title as a call to arms and lining up on both sides, waiting... for the signal to attack. Which would have been "Go".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Originally, [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) was the Meta site for the entire network. For a long time it was where you asked meta questions regardless of whether they were about Stack Overflow or the network at large. In [April of 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250024/359284), [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) became its own site, and is now where all network-wide meta questions belong. You can look at the [mso-mse-split](/questions/tagged/mso-mse-split) tag for related posts.

> And then there was Meta.SE.
> -- Someone, Somewhere

So since the split was pretty abrupt, many of the older questions fit on both MSO and MSE and it was decided to keep them wherever they currently lay.

---

Now, [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions [can be on any meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255291/359284), as [they are all aggregated into a giant list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250156/359284) in the long run. This means **you don't need to run to Meta.SE for every bug you see, especially Stack Overflow specific ones**. This includes things like discussing the [large close vote queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251489/359284),  [tagging requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284976/359284), and [design questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277200/feedback-requested-stack-overflow-design-update). This also includes bug reports like [triage-related ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284675/359284) (for now), [Stack Snippet issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272736/359284), and [question ban problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272453/359284).

If your bug report covers **all over of Stack Exchange**, and not just Stack Overflow specifically, it might be better to put it on Meta.SE. This includes [bug reports about chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243720/159034), [requests affecting all of Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116782/159034), and [Area51 issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234383/159034). Basically, **if it affects all of Stack Exchange or it's not actually related to Stack Overflow, it belongs on Meta.SE**.

---

To answer your question about where "https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248338/159034" should have gone...

- It's about the triage queue? **Meta.SO**
- It only affects Stack Overflow? **Meta.SO**
- It was already posted on Meta.SE? **Keep it on Meta.SE**

**You should not cross-post questions across both Meta.SO and Meta.SE.** If you created it on one or the other, leave it there. If it needs to be migrated, someone will migrate it for you (or tell you to move it).

Comment: So regarding my question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/can-the-reviews-history-also-include-the-consensus-of-our-reviews should i ask it here or in Meta Exchange ? or both ?

Comment: **Never both.** You were probably safer starting that on MSO, but at this point you're better off leaving it on MSE.

Comment: Since you can't get post-banned on MSO, is it a good idea to post here if you're banned on MSE?

Comment: @Narawa If you're post banned on MSE you probably have other issues that you need to deal with.

Comment: @narawagames MSE must have its own post-banning system. MSO is *not* MSE and should not be treated a such.

Answer (score 11):

I think you are over thinking this.  The last 2 paragraphs of [Tim Post's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250020/what-kind-of-questions-should-we-ask-on-meta-stack-overflow-and-on-meta-stack-ex/250073#250073) to the question you linked sum it very nicely:

> You don't have to go to MSE unless you want to, the community team and your moderators will take care of handling migrations for you, as they're needed.
>
> Put simply, MSE isn't something you even need to know about or think about, unless you want to.

In short, you can always ask on MSO for anything you want (related to SO or SE).  You don't need to worry about asking yourself "where should I post this".  If you don't know which is the best site, you are best asking on MSO.  If the question really needs to be on MSE, someone will move it for you.  But the Stack Exchange team doesn't really need you to post it anywhere.  If it is a good [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), they will see it regardless of where you post it.

The only exceptions are bugs and feature requests for [careers](/questions/tagged/careers), [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app), and [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) as the developers for those teams prefer the questions on MSE, however, again, you shouldn't necessarily worry about it.  Those tags wouldn't exist on MSO if they questions weren't welcome to some extent.

Answer (score 5):

For many years, Meta Stack Overflow (MSO) was where the exchange as a whole as discussed. However, as the exchange matured from one site to many MSO became an increasingly poor fit to house the discussions about the exchange.

This resulted in the creation of Meta Stack Exchange (MSE). At the time MSE was created, the entirety of MSO was moved there (which is why there is such a large amount of questions tagged stackoverflow there). While some content was moved back, a majority remains there for reasons.

Once the split occurred the general approach has been to ask questions which pertain to the entire exchange at MSE, and questions which pertain to individual sites (such as SO) at their site relevant metas (so MSO in this case).

tldr;

MSO : questions about issues related to Stack Overflow, or the software that drives it (may overlap with similarities to the way the overall exchange works which is fine)

MSE : questions about issues related to *every* Exchange, or the software that drives it.